# How to react to a NS ERROR FAILURE error in the browser's Javascript

Tags: javascript, exception, xmlhttprequest

In Firefox' JavaScript engine I do a (deprecated) synchronous `XMLHttpRequest` like this:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8780/BoilerData/invention.html', false);
request.send();

if (request.status === 200) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

Problem is when the server `myserver.com` is not running I get in the browser console a `NS ERROR FAILURE` error and the `else` part is not executed.

However  I would like to react to this error in JavaScript. How can I catch this error and react to it (e.g. with using another server) while still doing a a synchronous `XMLHttpRequest`.

#### Update

Here more details to the error message. In the console of my browser (Firefox 78.4.1esr) I see the following:

[image: Error in Firefox]

Comment: Not sure why the use of the old `XMLHttpRequest` instead of `await fetch()` is so popular, and even less sure why forcing asynchronous things to be synchronous and blocking the UI is such a trend these days... Synchronous requests were never a thing. It's not really deprecated because it's never been "precated"(?) in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer a synchronous request, try catch the `net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` exception:

```js
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'http:/myserver.com/bar/foo.txt', false);
try{
  request.send();
  if (request.status === 200) {
    //...
  }
}catch(e){
  console.log('Got an exception: ', e);
  //else ...
}
```

Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated, you may want to do `request.open` asynchronously, and put the `else` logic in `onerror` event processor:

```js
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'http:/myserver.com/bar/foo.txt', true);

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    //    ...
    } 
}
request.onerror = function() {
   console.log('An error occured! status = ', request.status);
   // what else {
   // ...
}

request.send();
```

Comment: Thanks for the code sample. You use a _asynchronous_ request, right? Does this mean reacting to the error is not possible with a synchronous_ request?

Comment: It's possible, but not recommended. See my update.

Comment: I tried your `try ...catch` solution, but the browser still quits the JS execution with a `NS ERROR FAILURE` and does _not_ go through the `catch` part.

Comment: Which kind of browser did you use? I tested it in Edge and Chrome，where it worked fine.

Comment: Using Firefox 78.4.1esr. Maybe it is a Firefox issue or a version specific problem...

Comment: OK, if you look at the console, the exception output should be following the `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error message, like: `Got an exception:  DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://myserver.com/bar/foo.txt'.
    at <anonymous>:4:11`

Comment: Sorry I only see `NS_ERROR_FAILURE:`. See bottom of question for screenshot.

Comment: What did you see when pressing the "Run code snippet" button under the code?

Comment: I see the _caught_ exception as you'd expect. So in _my _case it must be something else which prevents the failure from being caught. Don't worry about it it, I will try the `onerror` approach. It is the recommended way in any case.

Comment: OK, maybe it's some security option of your browser that blocks the event. You can try another browser to check it out. At least in my environment it works.